# How to get the total records details along with the query which is having a limit

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get the total records details along with the query which is having a limit

My `MySQL` query is given below

```
SELECT name FROM employees LIMIT 10
```

which will give me `10` rows, but the total records will be around `6000`. How can we get that also along with the above query

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees) AS cnt
FROM employees 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Sub-query`

```
SELECT nameFROM,
      (select count(1) from employees) as total_count 
From employees 
LIMIT 10
```

or `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT nameFROM,total_count 
From employees 
CROSS JOIN (select count(1) total_count  from employees) A
LIMIT 10
```

Adding `ORDER BY` to your query will make the result consistent

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) option in your query which will tell MySQL to count total number of rows disregarding LIMIT clause. You still need to execute a second query in order to retrieve row count, but it’s a simple query and not as complex as your query which retrieved the data. Usage is pretty simple. In you main query you need to add SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option just after SELECT and in second query you need to use FOUND_ROWS() function to get total number of rows

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS name FROM employees WHERE LIMIT 10

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: But I'm not getting 6000 for SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT NAME, 1 AS 'Obs' FROM employees LIMIT 10) 
union select 'RecsinTable', count(*) from employees
```